# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.googleResponse.responses[0]')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, google-vision

I am totally new at this, and I am using Google Vision with my React Native app on Expo to label documents. I based it off this project:

https://github.com/crowdbotics-apps/rngooglevisionapi-1400/blob/master/frontend/App.js

And I edited it to use Document Text Detection instead.

However, this error keeps coming up.

The only place I am using this.state.googleResponse.responses[0] in my code is:

```
    render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
                <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
                    {image ? null : (
                        <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>Smart Text Extractor</Text>
                    )}
                </View>

                <View style={styles.helpContainer}>
                    <View style={{ margin: 20 }}>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this._pickImage}
                            title="Pick an image from Gallery"
                            color="#3b5998"
                        />
                    </View>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this._takePhoto}
                        title="Take a photo"
                        color="#1985bc"
                    />

                    {this.state.googleResponse && (
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.googleResponse.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation}
                            extraData={this.state}
                            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <Text style={styles.textText}>
                                    Text Detected: {item.description}
                                </Text>
                            )}
                        />
                    )}

                    {this._maybeRenderImage()}
                    {this._maybeRenderUploadingOverlay()}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
```

My entire code is

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Image,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Button,
    FlatList,
    Clipboard
} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import Environment from './src/config/environment';
import firebase from './src/config/firebase';

//console.disableYellowBox = true;

async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });

    const ref = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref()
        .child(uuid.v4());
    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

    blob.close();

    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        image: null,
        uploading: false,
        googleResponse: null
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    }

    organize = array => {
        return array.map(function(item, i) {
            return (
                <View key={i}>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        });
    };

    _maybeRenderUploadingOverlay = () => {
        if (this.state.uploading) {
            return (
                <View
                    style={[
                        StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
                        {
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }
                    ]}
                >
                    <ActivityIndicator color="#fff" animating size="large" />
                </View>
            );
        }
    };

    _maybeRenderImage = () => {
        let { image, googleResponse } = this.state;
        if (!image) {
            return;
        }

        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    marginTop: 20,
                    width: 250,
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    elevation: 2
                }}
            >
                <Button
                    style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                    onPress={() => this.submitToGoogle()}
                    title="Analyze!"
                />

                <View
                    style={{
                        borderTopRightRadius: 3,
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 3,
                        shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
                        shadowOffset: { width: 4, height: 4 },
                        shadowRadius: 5,
                        overflow: 'hidden'
                    }}
                >
                    <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} />
                </View>
                <Text
                    onPress={this._copyToClipboard}
                    onLongPress={this._share}
                    style={{ paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
                />

                <Text>Raw JSON:</Text>

                {googleResponse && (
                    <Text
                        onPress={this._copyToClipboard}
                        onLongPress={this._share}
                        style={{ paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
                    >
                        {JSON.stringify(googleResponse.responses)}
                    </Text>
                )}
            </View>
        );
    };

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.description;

    _renderItem = item => {
        <Text>response: {JSON.stringify(item)}</Text>;
    };

    _share = () => {
        Share.share({
            message: JSON.stringify(this.state.googleResponse.responses),
            title: 'Check it out',
            url: this.state.image
        });
    };

    _copyToClipboard = () => {
        Clipboard.setString(this.state.image);
        alert('Copied to clipboard');
    };

    _takePhoto = async () => {
        let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3]
        });

        this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
    };

    _pickImage = async () => {
        let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3]
        });

        this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
    };

    _handleImagePicked = async pickerResult => {
        try {
            this.setState({ uploading: true });

            if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
                uploadUrl = await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
                this.setState({ image: uploadUrl });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            alert('Upload failed, sorry :(');
        } finally {
            this.setState({ uploading: false });
        }
    };

    submitToGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            this.setState({ uploading: true });
            let { image } = this.state;
            let body = JSON.stringify({
                requests: [
                    {
                        features: [
                            //{ type: 'TEXT_DETECTION'}, //maxResults: 5 },
                            { type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'}//, maxResults: 5 }
                        ],
                        image: {
                            source: {
                                imageUri: image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            let response = await fetch(
                'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' +
                    Environment['GOOGLE_CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY'],
                {
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: body
                }
            );
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            console.log(responseJson);
            this.setState({
                googleResponse: responseJson,
                uploading: false
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    render() {
        let { image } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state.googleResponse)

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
                        {image ? null : (
                            <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>Smart Text Extractor</Text>
                        )}
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.helpContainer}>
                        <View style={{ margin: 20 }}>
                            <Button
                                onPress={this._pickImage}
                                title="Pick an image from Gallery"
                                color="#3b5998"
                            />
                        </View>
                        <Button
                            onPress={this._takePhoto}
                            title="Take a photo"
                            color="#1985bc"
                        />

                        {this.state.googleResponse && (
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.googleResponse.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation}
                                extraData={this.state}
                                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                    <Text style={styles.textText}>
                                        Text Detected: {item.description}
                                    </Text>
                                )}
                            />
                        )}

                        {this._maybeRenderImage()}
                        {this._maybeRenderUploadingOverlay()}
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ebebeb',
        paddingBottom: 10
    },
    developmentModeText: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
        fontSize: 14,
        lineHeight: 19,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    contentContainer: {
        paddingTop: 30
    },

    getStartedContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 50,
        marginVertical: 50
    },

    getStartedText: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },

    helpContainer: {
        marginTop: 15,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    textText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '600'
    }
});

//export default App;
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: please console.log(this.state.googleResponse) and share response

Comment: hi thanks for the fast response. I am new at this, and i have no idea where to put it in my code. I will update my question to include the whole code. Please advise where I should put it.

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think google vision response contain text and bounding. Please update the FlatList component.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.googleResponse}
    extraData={this.state}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text style={styles.textText}>
                Text Detected: {item.text}
            </Text>
       )}
 />
```

**Note**: Make sure the this.state.googleResponse must be response of vision api. You can check it by using console.log(this.state.googleResponse) in render method.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the console.log doesn't return anything. The error is still there..